# Why can't I describe log streams but my function has required permissions

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I can't describe log streams using this code.

```
 const response = await cloudWatchLogs
  .describeLogStreams({
    logGroupName,
    logStreamNamePrefix: logStreamName,
  })
  .promise()
```

But I have added permissions to describe them in my role. What could be the problem? I have done my research and based on the role that I have created I should be able to do the following

1. Create log groups
2. Create log streams
3. describe log streams
4. put log events
5. tag resources
6. receive messages from sqs queue
7. delete messages from sqs queue
8. get queue attributes

I don't have problems with SQS actions. It's only describe log streams action that I can't do.

```
sqsLambdaRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: SQSLambdaRole 
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
        # note that these rights are needed if you want your function to be able to communicate with resources within your vpc
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: sqsLambdaPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow # note that these rights are given in the default policy and are required if you want logs out of your lambda(s)
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:DescribeLogStreams
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                    - logs:TagResource
                  Resource:
                    - 'Fn::Join':
                      - ':'
                      -
                        - 'arn:aws:logs'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
                        - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
                -  Effect: "Allow"
                   Action:
                     - sqs:ReceiveMessage
                     - sqs:DeleteMessage
                     - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
                   Resource: '*'
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are trying to access log streams that have ARNs matching in your CloudFormation policy?

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly understand, but doesn't this allow my function to access every log `log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*`?

Comment: It does. But have you checked that the log group you're trying to access matches this arn? Not all log groups are under `/aws/lambda`

Comment: @TofigHasanov  thanks. The policy gives permission to logs with a name that starts with `/aws/lambda/`. The name of the log group I am using doesn't start with `/aws/lambda`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue was due to log group not being under `/aws/lambda` path, which is what policy was giving access to here:

```
                  Resource:
                    - 'Fn::Join':
                      - ':'
                      -
                        - 'arn:aws:logs'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
                        - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
                        - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
```

So to fix this you need to change policy to allow prefix that your log group has.